# How to change NSCursor permanently in app area?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want my `NSCursor` became as `pointingHand` in all of my app.

I made this code below but I don´t think this is the way to go, because at first I tried to change the `NSCursor` via an action of a button. It worked, but as soon as I moved the mouse the `NSCursor`, the shape changed to macOS default one. Then, I tried this code:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            Color.blue
            Text("Hello, world!")
        }
        .onHover(perform: { value in
            NSCursor.pointingHand.push()
        })

    }
}
```

I don't like this code because `onHover` makes `NSCursor` update almost every second and I think `onHover` is competing with macOS all the time to change `NSCursor` to `pointingHand`. In this level of coding, it means that `onHover` could be replaced even with a timer and could do the same thing. So because of that, I am sure using `onHover` is not the best fit for my goal.

How can I change the `NSCursor` shape just for my app area without using the `onHover` modifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consult [the `NSCursor` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscursor#), we find a discussion of “cursor rectangles”:

> In Cocoa, you can change the currently displayed cursor based on the position of the mouse over one of your views. You might use this technique to provide visual feedback about what actions the user can take with the mouse. For example, you might display one of the resize cursors whenever the mouse moves over a portion of your view that acts as a custom resizing handle. To set this up, you associate a cursor object with one or more cursor rectangles in the view.

Let's write a [`ViewModifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewmodifier#) that sets up a cursor rectangle.

```
extension View {
  func cursor(_ cursor: NSCursor) -> some View {
    self.modifier(CursorModifier(cursor: cursor))
  }
}

struct CursorModifier: ViewModifier {
  let cursor: NSCursor

  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
      .background { Rep(cursor: cursor) }
  }
}
```

The modifier adds a [`background`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(alignment:content:)) view, of type `Rep`, to the modified view. But what is `Rep`? It's an [`NSViewRepresentable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/nsviewrepresentable#) that wraps a customized [`NSView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview#). The `NSView` overrides [`resetCursorRects`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/1483448-resetcursorrects) to create a cursor rect covering the entire `NSView`.

```
extension CursorModifier {
  private struct Rep: NSViewRepresentable {
    let cursor: NSCursor

    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSViewType {
      return NSViewType(cursor: cursor)
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSViewType, context: Context) {
      nsView.cursor = cursor
    }

    class NSViewType: NSView {
      var cursor: NSCursor

      init(cursor: NSCursor) {
        self.cursor = cursor
        super.init(frame: .zero)
      }
      
      required init?(coder: NSCoder) { fatalError() }

      override func resetCursorRects() {
        addCursorRect(bounds, cursor: cursor)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To test it, I'll set up a SwiftUI view containing a [`Text`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text#) (which shouldn't affect the cursor) and a [`TextField`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield#) (which should show [the `iBeam` cursor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscursor/1526109-ibeam) on hover).

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State var text: String = ""

  var body: some View {

    VStack {
      Spacer()
      Text("Hello, world!")
      TextField("Input:", text: $text)
      Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
    .cursor(.pointingHand)
  }
}
```

Result:

[image: Demo of the mouse pointer moving up and down the window. The cursor changes from the standard arrow to the pointing hand when it is in the window but not in the text field. It changes to the i-beam cursor when it is over the text field.]

Note that I had to put the [`Spacer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/spacer#)s in the [`VStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack#) to make the `VStack` fill the window. Otherwise, the window can be taller than the `VStack`, and the part of the window outside the `VStack` doesn't use the pointing hand.

Comment: Yes Sir, that is the way!